# Clarification regarding filters in R

Tags: r

I have three varaibles category,status and review in dataset new

```
category    status       review
  max       state          yes
  min       state          yes
  min       state          yes
  max       fine           yes
  NA        could state    yes
  max       state          yes
  NA        could state    yes
```

I have two condition to process

condition one

delete when `category = min` and `status = state`

i used below code

```
new1 <- new[!with(new,new$category=="min" &new$status=="state"),]
```

I got below output

```
category    status       review
  max       state         yes
  max       fine          yes
  NA        could state   yes
  max       state         yes
  NA        could state   yes
```

condition two: remove records having `category = min` and `status = could state`

```
new2 <- new1[!with(new1,new1$category=="min" &new1$status=="could state"),]
```

I was expecting below result

```
category    status       review
  max       state          yes
  max       fine           yes
  NA        could state    yes
  max       state          yes   
  NA        could state    yes
```

Output which i got is

```
category    status     review
  max       state       yes
  max       fine        yes
  NA        NA          NA
  max       state       yes
  NA        NA          NA
```

I am not sure why records are getting replaced by NA

Is there any other way to give both condition in one condition(remove when `category = min` and `status = state` and `could state`). I have referred other questions available

Comment: a suggestion, when using with you do not need to qualify the column names with the dataframe, so instead of `with(new1, new1$category...` you should write `with(new1, category...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a column contains an NA element, the logical condition returns NA for that element unless it is taken care off with `is.na` to return TRUE.  Here, I negated `(!`) to return FALSE for the NA elements in 'category'.  As per the OP's two conditions, we need to get TRUE for cases where 'category' is 'min' and 'status' is 'state'  OR (`|`) where 'category' is 'min' and 'status' is 'could state'.  Once we get that TRUE values, just negate (`!`) to convert TRUE to FALSE and viceversa.  Then, subset the rows based on that index ('i1').

```
i1 <- !with(new1, (category == "min" & !is.na(category) & status =="state")| 
           (category =="min" & !is.na(category) & status == "could state"))
new1[i1,]
#   category      status review
#1      max       state    yes
#4      max        fine    yes
#5     <NA> could state    yes
#6      max       state    yes
#7     <NA> could state    yes
```

---

A slightly more compact option would be to use `%in%` for multiple elements

```
i1 <- !with(new1, (category == "min" & !is.na(category) & 
                            status %in% c("state", "could state")))
new1[i1,]
#  category      status review
#1      max       state    yes
#4      max        fine    yes
#5     <NA> could state    yes
#6      max       state    yes
#7     <NA> could state    yes
```

If we use both as `%in%`, we can avoid the `is.na`

```
i1 <- !with(new1, (category %in% "min" & status %in% c("state", "could state")))
new1[i1,]
```

NOTE: In all the cases mentioned above, when using `with`, we don't need to do `new1$`, just use the column names to get the values.

---

Just to illustrate the previous point,

```
 v1 <- c(NA, 3, 4, 3)
 v1==3
 #[1]    NA  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Note that `==` returns NA for NA values.  If we use `is.na`

```
 v1 ==3 & !is.na(v1)
#[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Or this can be avoided by using `%in%` which return FALSE for `NA`

```
v1 %in% 3
#[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Regarding the NA rows, if we subset based on the `==` condition, the NA will remain as such

```
v1[v1==3]
#[1] NA  3  3
```

Suppose if 'v1' is a column in a `data.frame`, in place of NA, an additional NA row will return

```
d1 <- data.frame(v1)
d1[d1$v1==3,, drop=FALSE]
#   v1
#NA NA
#2   3
#4   3
```

#### data

```
new1 <- structure(list(category = c("max", "min", "min", "max", NA, "max", 
NA), status = c("state", "state", "state", "fine", "could state", 
"state", "could state"), review = c("yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", 
"yes", "yes", "yes")), .Names = c("category", "status", "review"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```